# Is this valid CSV?

Tags: csv

I have a csv file with the following single line:

`Some,Test,"is"thisvalid,or,not`

according to `cvslint.io` it's not valid csv:
[image]

However according to `https://www.toolkitbay.com/tkb/tool/csv-validator` it is valid csv.  Which site is lying?

Comment: If you ignore the double quotes it is

Comment: @IMSoP - Fair point.  So what you're saying is that technically this is valid csv, but that it may or may not be correctly parsed by certain tools as evident above.

Comment: Comments converted to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether it is "valid" or not depends on the definition you, and the websites you found, are using. If you asked about "well-formed XML", everyone would agree that should be based on the W3C standard; or "valid HTML" would now probably refer to the WHATWG Living Standard. "Valid CSV" has no such universal definition - although there are standards for CSV, they've been written after years of use, in the rather optimistic hope that existing implementations will be amended to follow them.

So neither tool is "lying", they just evidently disagree on what "valid" means.

A far more useful question than if CSV is "valid" is whether it is interpreted as you want by whatever tool you try to process it with. From a practical point of view, it's likely that the unusual positioning of quote marks might be interpreted *differently* by different tools, so is probably best avoided if interoperability is relevant to your use case.

Comment: Do you know of any parsers that would allow that? I’d guess they’d produce something like ‘[“Some”, “Test”, “\”is\”thisvalid”, “or”, “not”]‘?”; or just drop the double quotes altogether?

Comment: @ZachYoung A quick test shows that PHP's fgetcsv does the latter https://3v4l.org/qFvvv and so does Excel. I wouldn't be at all surprised to the see the former, though.

Answer (score 1):

For CSV format the reference is this https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180

And you have:

> Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas **should be enclosed in double-quotes**.

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote

Then your CSV is not valid.

If your columns are these

```
+------+------+---------------+----+-----+
| 1    | 2    | 3             | 4  | 5   |
+------+------+---------------+----+-----+
| Some | Test | "is"thisvalid | or | not |
+------+------+---------------+----+-----+
```

then valid version is this

```
Some,Test,"""is""thisvalid",or,not
```

And it's valid also for https://csvlint.io/

Comment: You've missed the next rule: "If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote". So *according to that particular specification*, the correct version is `Some,Test,"""is""thisvalid",or,not`

Comment: Meanwhile, that RFC doesn't claim to be "the reference" for the format, only to "document the format that seems to be followed by most implementations". It even links to 4 other examples of attempting to document or specify the format. The main purpose of the RFC is to officially register the "text/csv" MIME type.

Comment: @IMSoP here double-quotes are not used to enclose fields, than it should be ok also `Some,Test,""is"thisvalid",or,not`

Comment: @IMSoP ok, it's only an RFC, but it is the document cited in all the guidelines on the subject, and it is the most used by the software tools to validate CSV files. So I would use it in any pipeline in which you must validate a CSV and create the most interperable one

Comment: @IMSoP I prefer your output, and I'm editing my reply. Thank you

Comment: Many RFCs **are** the official standard for a protocol or format, but this one **explicitly says that it is not**. It exists to tick a box on a form that every MIME type registration should have a specification attached. Most notably, it is explicitly *not* what is implemented by Microsoft Excel, so anyone writing files intended for use with that should *not* be referring to that description. In this example, my copy of Excel doesn't reject the file, it simply removes the extra quote marks, interpreting it as `Some,Test,isthisvalid,or,not`

Comment: @IMSoP the CSV RFC is compliant also with Excel and it is what I expected
https://i.imgur.com/oe3JcdG.png